# Setting up a server to execute a Python Script

Tags: python, web, server

I am looking to create a very basic website that has a single feature. This feature works as follows:

- 1) The user inputs a URL to a website
- 2) My website will scrape the given website for necessary information
- 3) Apply whatever logic I need and return the processed information as a string
- 4) Allow user to download returned data in .txt format.

I am working on this project with one collaborator, and he has created the scraping and logic (steps 2 and 3) in Python. I have looked around stack overflow to see if it is possible to execute python scripts in a website, and the consensus seemed to be that I will require a server that executes python, and then make HTTP requests to my server.

Unfortunately, I'm quite a junior developer and lack a lot of understanding regarding web dev, and my attempts to "dive in" have left me with more questions than answers. We have a deadline that is approximately 3 days from now, and the only part that remains is to set up a server that can execute a specific python script upon HTTP requests.

I think that the source of my confusion is a lack of understanding regarding how exactly a server works, and was hoping that the kind folks here at stack overflow could help me in:

1) better understanding what's going on "under the hood" on the server side after an HTTP request arrives (or better yet, how does an HTTP request even arrive at all?)

2) Explain to me like I'm 5 what I'll need to do to deploy my website - namely all the in-between steps that receive little attention from the other posts here at stack overflow.

Some example questions that run through my head are below:

What type of server will I need?

How will I know if it can run Python?

How does the server know that I want to execute a certain script, while upon a user entering a my website's homepage URL, land at the home screen?

I've also read up on "middle layers" such as 'CGI' - what does this accomplish?

Is setting up a server reinventing the wheel? 
`enter code here`
Is there already a service out there that does what I'm looking for?

Comment: You might be well served with http://pythonanywhere.com/. Among other options, it allows you to set up a very simple flask app in no time. There's a lot of resources on Flask.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished a similar project *overnight* with a Python web framework called Django, simply by following their official tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Django abstracts away all the web stuff for you and there's plenty of documentation on deploying it in various environments. With such deadlines I suggest you to just follow the tutorial above and eventually adapt the example to your use case testing it on Django's built-in web server, then follow a guide on deploying Django projects in your production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I assume I can just plug and play my partner's code with imports?